# ImmutableList getting updating on updating referenced list

Tags: java, guava, immutablelist

I am trying to get a new `ArrayList` out of existing `ArrayList` and update a field in new list. But it is getting updated in old list also.

I have tried the following code:

```
absoluteEntitlements = findAbsoluteEntitlements(ImmutableList.copyOf(tenantEntitlements), everyoneEntitlements, "global");

private List<Entitlement> findAbsoluteEntitlements(ImmutableList<Entitlement> primaryEntitlements,
            List<Entitlement> secondaryEntitlements, String accessType) {
        List<Entitlement> absoluteEntitlements = new ArrayList<Entitlement>(primaryEntitlements);
    for (int i = 0; i < primaryEntitlements.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondaryEntitlements.size(); j++) {
            if (secondaryEntitlements.get(j).equals(primaryEntitlements.get(i))
                    && "false".equals(primaryEntitlements.get(i).getAccessType())) {
                absoluteEntitlements.get(i).setAccessType(accessType);
            }
        }
    }
    return absoluteEntitlements;
}
```

Please provide a solution, where I am doing wrong.

Comment: *"where I am doing wrong"* You're thinking that _everything_ in the immutable list is immutable as well, but this is not the case. The `ImmutableList` just prevents manipulating the list itself (e.g. adding or deleting items). It can't protect from changing the state of the contained instances. Either make your `Entitlement` immutable (and return a new instance if a field should be updated) or create a method to perform a deep copy of your `tenantEntitlements` list (means, it also copies the `Entitlement` items in that list).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy list of your custom objects then before adding object to new list you have to do **cloning** of object.

```
List<Entitlement> absoluteEntitlements = new ArrayList<Entitlement>();
for (Entitlement e : primaryEntitlements) {
    absoluteEntitlements.add(e.clone());
}
```

Make sure your Entitlement class should support cloning of object.

Comment: Thanks @Akash this is helpful.